# Providing strong guarantees in methods/classes that were not designed with exception-safety in mind

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I have a design problem. Let's start by saying that this code

```
struct Trial{
    const double a;
    Trial(double a_) : a(a_){}
};

int main(){
    Trial t1(1.);
    Trial t2(2.);
    t1 = t2;
}
```

doesn't compile, because `Trial::operator=` isn't built by default by the compiler, since `Trial::a` is `const`. And that's pretty much obvious.

Now the point is this, code first

```
struct Trial{
    const double a;
    Trial(double a_) : a(a_){}
};

struct MyClass : private Trial{
    MyClass(double a_) : Trial(a_), i(0) {};
    void wannaBeStrongGuaranteeMemberFunction(){
        MyClass old(i);
        bool failed = true;
        //... try to perform operations here
        if(failed)
            *this = old;
    }
    unsigned int i;
};

int main(){
    MyClass m1(1.);
    m1.wannaBeStrongGuaranteeMemberFunction();
}
```

I need to provide strong exception safety for some of the methods of a class, which is derived from `Trial`. Such methods perform an endless series of operations on an endless series of members (`i` in the example) and this makes it unpractical to "manually" revert the operations. Therefore I decided that it's better to perform a copy of the whole class and copy it back if anything fails.

Small parenthesis, the code is just an example. Everything is much more complex in the legacy real-world code.
In this example, copying just `i` would be fine, but this is not the case in the real code.
Moreover, the operations have multiple (and complex) paths of executions, so that it would be a pain to "read" them as "transactions".
Moreover, I'm implementing this using scope guards, so exceptions are being managed correctly in the real code.

Of course the whole thing doesn't compile, because of the line `*this = old`.

How would you solve the problem/address the issue?

Comment: Crazy idea: `this->~MyClass(); new (this) myClass(old);`

Comment: why not implement copy constructor? that should help i think

Comment: @Opsenas How would that help? The problem is assigning to an *already existing* object with `const` members.

Comment: @jrok, this doesn't compile either

Comment: @opsenas because I don't want to place the burden of adding new lines to the copy constructor when, if ever, new data members are added to the class. I wouldn't even trust myself to remember to do this in 1 month time (is this sufficiently politically correct?)!

Comment: @BoBTFish you are right, but const downcasting could be an option (a very unpleasant one)

Comment: @StefanoFalasca You need to [include `<new>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e26329a33e12995d2976bd8b6d7cd730-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419).

Comment: @jork you can make this an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jrok Very crazy.  And what happens if the copy exits via an exception?  You're left with an object on which you cannot call the destructor.  If it's a local object, you're screwed, and if it's dynamically allocated, you can't delete it, so at the least, you have a memory leak.

Comment: That's why I said it's crazy. I won't post it as an answer, don't worry.

Comment: @jrok At least you recognize it as an anti-pattern.  Something you shouldn't ever do.  (People did use it back in the days before exceptions.  But it still caused problems if you ever inherited from the class.)

Comment: @JamesKanze can you please explain me better what are the problems with this solution? I didn't see any and I struggle to learn!!!

Comment: The point is that copy constructor called by placement new might throw and at that point destructor of *this has already been called.

Comment: so, is there any use for this kind of call of the new?

Comment: placement new by itself is useful, of course (think memory pools). But in your situation... only if you absolutely know copy-ctor won't throw.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca I clearly stated it: what happens if you leave the copy constructor by an exception.  You've destructed the object, but you haven't reconstructed it, so you cannot destruct it again without undefined behavior (and probably all sorts of problems in practice as well).

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Placement `new` is used when you need to separate allocation and initialization, e.g. as in `std::vector`.  If you use placement new, then all construction of the object at that address should be using placement new, and all destruction should use the explicit destructor call.

Comment: @jrok Only if you can guarantee for all time that the copy constructor will _never_ throw, _and_ that no one will ever derive from your class.  Of course, in that case, your class is so simple that you don't need any of this anyway.

Comment: Could you explain why inheriting is a problem, please?

Comment: @JamesKanze I join the request, can you explain the problems with inheritance?

Comment: @StefanoFalasca What will the assignment operator in the derived class do?  If it calls the base class `operator=` (the default), it has changed the type of the object, which will have disasterous consequences when the object goes out of scope, and if it doesn't, then the base class won't be assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is to modify `Trial` so that it supports
assignment as well.  Barring that, and if the only reason you
want to support assignment is to provide the strong guarantee,
you could implement your own assignment operator, preferrably
private, which ignored the base class; since you know that the
two base classes will be identical, there's no need to assign
between them.

Note that the strong guarantee more often involves swapping than
assignment.  Which doesn't change the problem: you can't swap
two versions of `Trial`, either.  You'ld most likely have 
something like:

```
class MyClass : private Trial
{
    class Protected
    {
        bool myCommitted;
        MyClass* myOwner;
        MyClass myInstance;
    public:
        MyClass( MyClass& owner )
            : myCommitted( false )
            , myOwner( &owner )
            , myInstance( owner )
        {
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            if ( myCommitted ) {
                myOwner->swap( myInstance );
            }
        }
        MyClass& instance() { return myInstance; }
        void commit() { myCommitted = true; }
    };

public:

    void protectedFunc()
    {
        Protected p( *this );
        p.instance().unprotecedVersionOfFunc();
        //  ...
        p.commit();
    }
```

Any exception will leave the object unchanged.  (You can, of
course, reverse the logic, making the modifications on `this`,
and swapping if uncommitted.)  The advantage of doing things
this way is that you will also "undo" any changes in memory
allocation, etc.

Finally: do you really want to use a const member in `Trial`.
The usual way of implementing this would be to make `a`
non-const but private, and only provide a getter.  This means
that `Trial::a` is effectively const, *except* for complete
assignment.

Comment: You are right with all respect. The only point in making the member  const is that I want to be sure that nobody else tries to modify it  without being aware that he/she shouldn't. The point being: the class is derived from Trial for the sole purpose of inheriting its members, which are protected. I don't want for derived classes to modify those members. I know this is bad, but this is not my design.

Comment: another advantage of not reversing the logic is that you make only one copy in the worst case (normal operations).

Comment: Protected destructor should be no-throw

Comment: @StefanoFalasca I normally only make one copy, regardless.  I'll swap to get the right version where I want it in the end (and my swap functions are very cheap, since a shallow swap is always acceptable).

Comment: @StefanoFalasca *All* destructors should be no-throw.  (Well, almost all.)  But I don't declare them as such, because if I write `throw()`, some compilers might warn that this is deprecated, and if I write `noexcept`, other compilers won't understand.  (The same thing holds for `swap`, of course.  One of the points of using `swap` is that it can always be implemented shallow, so it never has to acquire new resources, or do anything which can fail.)

Comment: I was not speaking about exception specification, but about the implementation, which should catch(...)

Comment: @StefanoFalasca catch what?  The implementation doesn't do anything that can throw.

Comment: cannot myOwner->swap( myInstance ); throw (as far as we know)?

Comment: @StefanoFalasca It shouldn't, if written correctly.  Although not required by the standard, it's a pretty general requirement otherwise.  The whole purpose of having it is to support things like this (and cheap implementations of move).  And we know, since we're the ones who write it.